# Regex: Simple Match

Tags: python, regex

I have no experience in regex, I tried dabbling in it a few times, but never stuck to it.

I'm scrapping a site in `python` using BeautifulSoup and have come across `img` tags that have an `id` attribute that can be used to pull my wanted data. But I need a regex to pull all the data matching the `id` constraints. The constraints are as follow:

`img-%d`: %d is a whole digit ranging from 0 - 255

`<img id="img-1" ...>
<img id="img-2" ...>
<img id="img-3" ...>
...
<img id="img-25" ...>
...
<img id="img-255" ...>`

In regex how would I write the expression to look for `img-%d`.
I know `\d` is used to match a single digit but I have 300 possible digits, the `[0-9]` doesn't work here.

Code is real simple I'm just missing the regex.

```
#regex_needed = re.comple( 'expresion here )
soup.find_all('img', attrs={'id': regex_needed})
```

Comment: Have you tried [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)??

Comment: Im using BeautifulSoup. Code is `soup.find_all('img', attrs={'id': regex_needed})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
img-\d{1,3}
```

which would match atleast 1 and at most 3 characters

```
import re

pat=re.compile(r'img-\d{1,3}')

soup.find_all('img', attrs={'id': pat}
```

Comment: Nice and simple, I like it. How would I add the 'img-' into a re.compile() method?

Comment: @Crispy i have edited the answer to include `img-` as well. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would be as simple as just adding 'img-' in there.

Comment: @Crispy you are always welcome :) Regex is there to make things much simpler

Comment: Yeah, I had 10 lines of code to account for the one regular expression. I need to put aside time to practice it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a more specific regex than nu11p01n73R's that only works with 0-255, try this as your pattern:

```
\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b
```

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked at the source, I think I like using the mapping method provided by `nu11p01n7e3R`. It's a clean a simple read.